# "} Expected"Yet the bracket is there

Tags: c#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Looting : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Rect inventoryWindowRect = new Rect (300, 100, 400, 400);
    private bool inventoryWindowShow = false;

    private Dictionary<int, string> lootDictionary = new Dictionary< int, string>()
    {
        {0, string.Empty},
        {1, string.Empty},
        {2, string.Empty},
        {3, string.Empty},
        {4, string.Empty},
        {5, string.Empty},
        {6, string.Empty},
        {7, string.Empty},
        {8, string.Empty}
    };

    ItemClass itemObject = new ItemClass();

    private Ray mouseRay;
    private RaycastHit rayHit;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        //display dictionary
        lootDictionary[0] = itemObject.arrowItem.name;
        lootDictionary[1] = itemObject.breadItem.name;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

        mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Physics.Raycast(mouseRay, out rayHit);      
            if (rayHit.collider.transform.tag == "lootable corpse")
            {
                inventoryWindowShow = true;
            }
            // Closes loot window
            if (Input.GetButtonDown(KeyCode.I))
            {
                inventoryWindowShow = false;
            }
        }   


    void OnGUI()
    {

        if (inventoryWindowShow)
        {
            inventoryWindowRect = GUI.Window(0, inventoryWindowRect, inventoryWindowMethod, "corpse");
        }
    }

    void inventoryWindowMethod (int WindowId)
    {

        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(0, 50, 400, 400));

        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        if (GUILayout.Button(lootDictionary[0], GUILayout.Height (50)))
        {
            if (lootDictionary[0] != string.Empty)
            {
                InventoryGUI.inventoryNameDictionary[0] = lootDictionary[0];
                lootDictionary [0] = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button(lootDictionary[1], GUILayout.Height(50)))
        {
            if (lootDictionary[1] != string.Empty)
            {
                InventoryGUI.inventoryNameDictionary[1] = lootDictionary[1];
                lootDictionary [1] = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button(lootDictionary[2], GUILayout.Height(50)))
        {
            if (lootDictionary[2] != string.Empty)
            {
                InventoryGUI.inventoryNameDictionary[2] = lootDictionary[2];
                lootDictionary[2] = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        GUILayout.EndArea();
    } 
}
```

The problem is line 51. Any ideas how to correct it? "}  Expected" error I've tried as many combinations of things. I've also tried commenting out the block and nothing happens. I'm trying to a looting system for a game. using unity 3D.

Comment: Could you mark line 51 with a comment?

Comment: telling us the line number doesn't help without line numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the closing `}` for the `Update` function. As a result of this, all the other braces are out of sync.

Comment: You beat me to it by 5 seconds! :)

Comment: You beat me too. It's like competitive Where's Waldo

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")){
                Physics.Raycast (mouseRay, out rayHit);     
                if (rayHit.collider.transform.tag == "lootable corpse")
                    {
                        inventoryWindowShow = true;
                    }
                //  Closes loot window
                if (Input.GetButtonDown(KeyCode.I)){
                        inventoryWindowShow = false;
                        }
            }
```

Where's your closing bracket....? Try adding a bracket at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another } at the end.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It is the answer to the question.